# why viewbinding makes display incorrectly?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

XML layout code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#DA2020">

</LinearLayout>
```

activity kotlin code:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
  }
}
```

When I write like this, the activity looks not like what I want:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2YvS.png)

The red background fill the whole screen.

But if I change `setContentView(binding.root)` to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`, the activity displays normally:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPxUp.png)

Why I can not use viewbinding in setContentView to achieve this? Is this a bug or some other reasons?

Comment: An Activity is always full screen, so probably using binding ignores attributes that specify activity height. You can achieve the same effect in both if you nest another 50dp layout in your current layout. Why do you need an activity that's so small?

Comment: @RazvanS. I am just a beginner of android developing and curious why there is difference.

Comment: Yeah I think this is an edge case, generally your Activity's layout will be `match_parent` because you want it to fill the Window your app is given. I *think* it's actually `setContentView` that's doing this - I quickly debugged it and `binding.root` *does* have a `height` attribute with the correct value when it's passed in, so I think `setContentView` is the thing deciding to ignore that. Haven't dived into it though - and this really is an edge case!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Viewbinding will inflate layout without parent,so some layoutParams not work.If you setContentView with layoutId,android will inflate it with content parent.

Comment: Can I set "content parent" in ActivityMainBinding.inflate function? If I can, how should I write?

Comment: @SAC.Aiden you have access to the parent/container in e.g. `Fragment`'s `onCreateView` method - you don't have access to one in the `Activity` though (as far as I'm aware!), `setContentView` internally searches for a special internal top-level container to set the `Activity`'s view on

Comment: i think issue with same id with different layout view